# Are LLMs the quickest, most cost-effective way to assess affinity between two texts?

Tags: llm, openai, nlp, transformers

I would like to compare thousands of text descriptions with a specific 'master' input and receive boolean (true/false) results for each comparison, based on their affinity.

The following is an example about *chess*:

Master Input:

```
I've got 7 years of gaming experience in online chess games.
```

Comparison Inputs:

```
Input 1:'Has played chess for 5 - 10 years.'
Input 2:'Has played online games.'
Input 3:'Played chess tournaments for 8 years.'
...
Input 50000:'As an experienced artisan, she has been building chess pieces for 30 years.'
```

Desired Task:

```
Assess each comparison input against the master input and determine if they match
providing a 'true' or 'false' result for each.
```

Expected Results:

```
Output 1: True
Output 2: True
Output 3: False
...
Output 50000: False
```

I've experimented with various methods, including OpenAI's API with GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 models, and while the results are nearly satisfactory, I'm uncertain if they're the ideal tools for the task. The approach doesn't scale well, especially considering speed and cost, given the thousands of comparisons I need to perform simultaneously. Are there more efficient alternatives? I've come across [question-answering transformers](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/question_answering) that I can run locally or more generic APIs like [Google's Natural Language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language?hl=en) or [Microsoft Azure AI Language](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/ai-services/ai-language) but remain unsure if they meet my needs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance is obviously more cost-effective. If not good enough for you, please edit your question to say why. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I am a human and I don't fully understand what is the criteria by which you decided to approve 1,2 and disqualify 3. I can come up with decent arguments why 1,2 should be False and 3 should be True and vice-versa. it all depends on your specific emphasis.